# Google Map's Alternative

Tags: maps

So I am building a website that will be using map algorithms heavily for things such as:

- POI
- Routing from A to B then to C
- Traffic

However, Google has a limit of 2,500 API requests per day, and I was wondering what other alternatives I have.

Because each users queries could possibly change the route, calling the google api for each person could use up the allocated API slots quite quickly. What options do I have?

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ever consider [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)?

Perhaps this helps:
http://www.ns-tech.co.uk/blog/2008/08/using-openstreetmap-overview-part-2-javascript-apis/

Comment: I have looked at OSM, but cannot find any routing API's that go with it.

Comment: Ok, I must admin, I never used OSM as a developer, I just threw it in because you were looking for a free alternative to Google Maps. I googled and found [OpenRouteService](http://openrouteservice.org/index.php). Perhaps you find a service in [their wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters#Route_service_comparison_matrix) that could help you?

Comment: Hm, I think the stuff on their Wiki about [ORS RouteLink](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#ORS_RouteLink) is the API desciption. After you used their map output to generate a routing, you can download the route in different formats including XML. I read in a forum (german, [XML representation of OpenRouteService](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=7775)), that you should ask them, if you may use that out programmatically. Their may be a reason, why it isn't described.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Did you find the answers to the questions you posted as comments? They might help in the future for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Google Maps API for Business" and make up to 100,000 requests per day.

**Related**

- [Google Maps API licensing](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)
- [Why Google Maps API for Business?](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html)

Comment: Starting at $10,000 per year? http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html

Comment: I am looking for a free alternative though, as my website is solely run off of advertising.

Comment: @Pat841: Your question doesn't say it has to be free. $10000 per year for up to 100,000 queries per **day** works out to be very cheap per query. If you do choose a non-free solution you could try to pass on the charge to some of your users. E.g. you could have 1000 users that pay $10 per year (not much) for up to 50 queries per day and let the other users use up to 5 queries per day for free. Many people are willing to pay a small amount of money for a good web site they use a lot. Or you could keep your service free and try to get more money from advertising as your site grows.